# access keycloak principal in @query Jparepository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, keycloak

i'm using keycloak along with spring boot, and i'm trying to access the principal object on a custom query in my JPA repository

my query :

```java
 @Query(value = "SELECT CAST (CASE WHEN COUNT(p) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) FROM product WHERE p.created_by = ?#{authentication.name} AND p.name = ?#{name}",nativeQuery = true)
 public abstract boolean existsByNameForCurrentUser(String name);
```

i've added this bean on my configuration:

```java
   @Bean
    public SecurityEvaluationContextExtension securityEvaluationContextExtension() {
        return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
    }
```

the error i'm getting is :

```java
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'authentication' cannot be found on object of type 'java.lang.Object[]' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

the principal object is accessible anywhere on my project, so i don't know why i'm getting this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that should be `?#{ principal?.username }`

Comment: it's not mandatory, according to the docs, By exposing the SecurityEvaluationContextExtension bean, all of the Common Security Expressions are available within the Query ( including the authentication object )